# Alternate in observables sequence

Tags: rxjs

I have n observables, each emitting an event with array of values fetched from a rest API. How can I merge these observables such that it takes values from each sequence one by one. Consider the following marble diagram, where A,B and C are observable sequences and each array is an observable.

```
A -[1,2,3]---[11,12,13]---[21,22,23]--->
B -[4,5]-------[14,15,16]-----[24,26]-->
C -[7,8,9,19]---[17,18,19]---[27,28]--->
```

Expected Sequence of output after merging

```
A+B+C -1-4-7-2-5-8-3-9-19-11-14-17-12-15-18-13-16-19-21-24-27-22-26-28-23->
```

Zip might look like one of the solution but I don't want to use it because if any one of the observables complete, values emitted by other observables is ignored. Also I have n observables, zip might result in lot of nesting of observables.

Comment: your operation look like normal `merge`

Comment: @FanCheung Merge cant guarantee the sequence order that I am trying to achieve.

Comment: I think I don't understand how you want to generate the sequence. Where `-3-9-19-` came from? I looks like it should be `-3-14-19-`.

Comment: @martin 14 belongs to the second event of the observable B. The idea is to consume the n th event of each observable and then take on the n+1th event.

Comment: So for example `-[7,8,9,19]-` is an Observable?

Comment: @martin Yes! I'll edit my question to make it more clear.

Comment: I think @FanCheung was right. It really looks like just `merge` with nested Observables. In real world use-case you'll never have two Observables emit at exactly the same time so the order of emissions from all sources will be the same.